# Codes of Python in Jupyter Notebook doesn't connect with DataBase in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, connection, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

At first I thought that only `insert_one()` function is giving Error. But All functions gave same Error.
I think I couldn't connect with my database in MongoDB. So I have been taking all these errors still.

Please help me solve these errors.

```python
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://elifbeyzatok:<password>@cluster0.2n6wagj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["dataBase"]  #database oluşturduk
collection = db["musteri"] #collection oluşturduk 

data = {"name": "Elif", "age": "20"}
collection.insert_one(data)
```

I wrote these codes. But I took **OperationFailure **

Comment: Would you edit your question and include the full error message?

Comment: Have you tried to check connection info? you can try by printing cluster.server_info() in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your database's admin's **userName** and **password** to correctly connect.

```python
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://userName:password@cluster0.2n6wagj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["dataBase"]  #database oluşturduk
collection = db["musteri"] #collection oluşturduk 

data = {"name": "Elif", "age": "20"}
collection.insert_one(data)
```

Comment: So the problem was a typo?